# header 404 not found - not work with\on\in Firefox 57.0.3 (64b)

Tags: php, http, firefox, https, http-status-code-404

```
<?php
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
```

No output on\in page.

---

**why is that? and what to do to see the error page?**
[image: path to 404.php-script]

[image: no output in firefox]

---

### reply to the first comment

[image: reply to the first comment]

Comment: You're not seeing any output because you haven't created any. The body of a 404 not found page isn't magically created for you simply by throwing a 404. If you want a nice-looking "Not Found" page, you have to actually build it. (Or tell your web server where to find it.)

Comment: @AlexHowansky , see above. have any ideas?

Comment: In your second example, the page is generated by Apache because it couldn't find the requested file. In your first example, the file was found, and executed, and it generated no output.

Comment: @AlexHowansky , aha, then I just need to read it myself, create an error page and print it out. `But I want the answer from the server to be 404. how to do it?`

Comment: The answer from the server *is* 404, that's what `header()` does. The content of the page itself is irrelevant but usually contains some helpful message like, "That page doesn't exist, so here is a kitten." If you want this page to be the default error handler for your whole site, you can use `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` in your Apache config. Then, if you request a page that doesn't exist, you'll get this page instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not seeing any output because you haven't created any. The body of a 404 not found page isn't magically created for you simply by throwing a 404. If you want a nice-looking "Not Found" page, you have to actually build it. (Or tell your web server where to find it.) Note that the header value is what makes a 404 page. The content of (or even the presence of) the body is irrelevant.

In your second example, the page is generated by Apache because it couldn't find the requested file. In your first example, the file was found, and executed, and it generated no output.

If you want to design a nice custom 404 page, you can put your pretty content into this file, and then set it to be the default error handler for your whole site by using `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` in your Apache config. Then, whenever you request a page that doesn't exist, you'll get this page instead.

Comment: i already saw. I asked a stupid question, but I will not delete it. for me the server response code is more important. Already decided https://itmages.ru/image/view/6373722/ab1397c5